# Compiling log4cpp lib on iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I am making a iPhone App. I am trying to use log4cpp libraray for logging in my project. I can statically compile this library on MAC OS using Makefile. When I try to use this lib woth my Iphone project, I geta linker error stating I need to compile this library against armv7 architecture. I don't know how to modify the makefile to compile against armv7 architecture. So I created a XCode project and add all the source files and tried to create a static libg of log4cpp against armv7 architecture, but I am getting too many compilation errors.

Please help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're running the compiler on an iPhone, you mean _for_ iOS.

Comment: Is this library compiled for iOS?